# Can anyone identify these three military uniforms?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

Can anyone help identify these 3 uniforms?

I have recently found out they could possibly be American military. The middle man is my great great uncle and sadly I have no other info to go on I’m afraid, so it’s going to be a long haul!

[image: Three men in uniform]

I’ve noticed that bottle in the pocket of the man standing and the cigar in the seated man's mouth on the right. 
I only know the standing man was born in Ireland and emigrated to America in the early 1900s.

Comment: When and where was your great great uncle in the picture born? That will help to identify/confirm which war vintage the uniforms are.

Comment: Hi Jenko and welcome to the site! Is that a bottle of liquor in his pocket?  Are those civilian clothes under the jacket?  Perhaps he was involved in civil defense.  Picture is not so good (low resolution and tilted)  can you provide a better one?  Can't make out details on cap and cuffs for example which will tell the tale of the seated men.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I’ve noted that ?bottle and ?cigar in seated mans mouth. I only know he was born in Ireland and emigrated to America in the early 1900s. I will try to add a clearer photo but the photo itself is not very good at all. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an opinion question - we've got an excellent track record with photo identification questions. (someone flagged the question for closure as opinion based; everyone has their right to their own opinion, but I personally don't think this is an opinion based question.)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Mark is referring to a close vote using the reason 'opinion based'. The new photo and information should make this possible to ID however.

Comment: Do you know where in 'America' he went? Anything more about his personal history? A more specific timeline (even if just some single dates)?

Comment: Are these guys brothers?

Comment: No I’m afraid I don’t have any information. I was hoping that by getting their uniforms identified that would give me more to work with. The man standing is definitely no relation to the other two. I can’t be sure if the two seated men are related or not.

Comment: I wonder if the three fellows are wearing costumes provided by some photography emporium for souvenir purposes,  As uniforms none of them really appear to fit.  The rifle is a small bore civilian type. No discernible insignia on army type jacket.  All three have more than just a missed button unbuttoned.  Doesn't scream "costumes," but certainly whispers it.

Comment: Thank you, you comments very appreciated